# Trying to generate string of 30 random numbers as a string

Tags: matlab, random, mutators

I'm making a genetic algorithm and I'm having trouble with the mutation. What I want to do is generate 30 random characters which will act as 10 states in my finite state machine (10 sets of 3 digits), the first digit of each 3 must be between 1-4, while the other 2 digits must be between 0-9.

Once I've generated my numbers I have to convert them into a 30 character string. I'd like to only mutate something like every fifth digit too.

This is what I'm currently trying:

```
 % mutate probability 0.2
 if (rand < 0.2)
        % pick best chromosome to mutate
            mut = combo{10};

            for t = 3:30
               mut(t) = num2str(randi([0,9]));
            end
  end
```

What I currently can't do is mutate only every nth digit or make sure that the first of every 3 digits is between 1-4 while keeping the others between 0-9.

In case it's helpful: `combo{10}` represents `110202132224154246176368198100`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not fully understand what you by mutating the strings, but to get a string of 30 random numbers, you can simply do as follows:

```
str_r = sprintf('%d',  randi([0,9],1,30));
# modify selected characters.
str_r(1:3:end) =  sprintf('%d',  randi([1,4],1,10));
```

Example result `str_r` is:

```
299334478355384287226314472383
```

Comment: Mutating the string just means altering a few digits, sorry if I worded it wrong.

My strings consist of 10 sets of 3 digits all merged together, so every the first and digit of each set must be between 1-4, but the other two digits must be between 0-9 E.g. 198 486 376 ...

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: @JmJ I ammended the anwser

Comment: When I try to add it to an array of strings using `first_gen = ['';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';'';''];` and `first_gen(i) = {str_r};` I get the error `Conversion to char from cell is not possible.`

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: To get cell from str_r just use: `c = num2cell(str_r)`

Comment: @JmJ Maybe its new problem, or it depends on the context of your code. You can create new question, and provide more details and examples.